# Syncfusion Grid Not Loading Dates When Filtering

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

Using an syncfusion grid to render a table of data. When filtering the "Line Approved Date", the mini window remains in a loading state indefinitely.

[image]

The filter function is working for the other columns.
Any ideas on how to make it so that the dates appear in filter window?

Here is some code for context:

```
//note - order of grouping header columns is hard coded
function GetColumns() {
    var output = [
        {
            field: "LineApprovedDate",
            headerText: "Line Approved Date",
            type: "date",
            format: { type: 'date', format: 'MM/dd/yyyy' },
            clipMode: 'EllipsisWithTooltip',
            width: 70
         }
    ];
            
    return output;
}

window.groupingHeader = function (args) {
    '<table class="e-table history-grid-group-headers" style="background: #fafafa;">' + '<tbody>' +
    '<td class="e-rowcell group-headercell" role="gridcell" aria-colindex="12">' 
    + (item.LineApprovedDate === null ? "" : moment(item.LineApprovedDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))+ '</td>' +
    '</tr >' + '</tbody></table>';
     return groupHeader;
}

//grid configurations
window.SetupGrid = function () {
    SetUpGroupingHeaderData();

    var opts = {
        dataSource: coData,
        allowSorting: true,
        allowFiltering: true,
        filterSettings: { type: 'Excel' },
        allowGrouping: true,
        groupSettings: {
            captionTemplate: '#groupingheader-template',
            showDropArea: false,
            columns: ["PoLineNumber"]
        },
        enableHover: false,
        allowSelection: false,
        height: GetHistoryGridHeight(),
        width: '100%',
        columns: GetColumns(),
        showColumnMenu: true,
        columnMenuItems: ['SortAscending', 'SortDescending', 'AutoFit', 'AutoFitAll', 'Filter'],
        enableVirtualization: true,
        allowResizing: true,
        resizeStop: function (args) {
            var index = args.column.index;
            $('.history-grid-group-headers td:nth-of-type(' + index + ')').outerWidth(args.column.width);
        },
        clipMode: "EllipsisWithTooltip",
        gridLines: "Both",
 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the data from the API call showed that the date related data was being received as a string. Adding the following function converts the date related data to a date type.

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.LineApprovedDate != null) {
         d.LineApprovedDate = new Date(d.LineApprovedDate);
    }
})
```